# Dotnet test doesn't run tests in GitHub Actions

Tags: .net, github-actions

I am trying to create a GHA workflow to build and test my dotnet project.

That's the workflow file:

```
name: build and test

on:
  push:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
    paths:
    - '**.cs'
    - '**.csproj'

env:
  DOTNET_VERSION: '7.0' # The .NET SDK version to use

jobs:
  build-and-test:
    
    name: build-and-test-${{matrix.os}}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}
      
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore Starmap/Starmap.sln
      
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build Starmap/Starmap.sln --configuration Release --no-restore
      
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: isbang/compose-action@v1.4.1
      with:
        compose-file: "infra.yaml"
    
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test Starmap/Starmap.sln --no-restore --verbosity normal
```

All steps succeeded but the tests aren't really running (I purposely changed a test to make sure it fails but it didn't)

The output I am getting from the `dotnet test` step is also looking partial.

```
Run dotnet test Starmap/Starmap.sln --no-restore --verbosity normal
  dotnet test Starmap/Starmap.sln --no-restore --verbosity normal
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    DOTNET_VERSION: 7.0
    DOTNET_ROOT: /usr/share/dotnet
  
Build started 02/18/2023 11:41:46.
     1>Project "/home/runner/work/Starmap/Starmap/Starmap/Starmap.sln" on node 1 (VSTest target(s)).
     1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
         Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
     1>Done Building Project "/home/runner/work/Starmap/Starmap/Starmap/Starmap.sln" (VSTest target(s)).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.67
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the individual test projects instead of the solution? I've seen a few different ways in which that ends up being more reliable. (I don't know why, but it's an easy enough change to make, usually.)

Comment: After the `build` step, there's a second `checkout`. Is that intentional? The project path in the logs i.e. `/home/runner/work/Starmap/Starmap/Starmap/Starmap.sln` also indicates multiple subdirectories i.e. `Starmap/Starmap/Starmap`. You might want to verify and fix this too.

Comment: @Azeem The double checkout was the issue apparently, now the test output is making sense!

Comment: @EliranTurgeman: Good. [`actions/checkout`](https://github.com/actions/checkout) checks out the repo and then `cd` into the checked-out repo directory. `dotnet test` was running into the newly checked-out repo which was unbuilt. Also, you may observe in the logs that it's building in the debug mode but your build step builds it in release mode.